# Wordpress CPT и СT

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет. Такая проблема, создал кастомный тип записей (products) и в ней создал кастомную таксономию (products-categories) и одну категорию (electronic). 
Если создать запись кастомного типа этой категории, то ссылка на него получается в виде `Home / CPT / Single Post`. Как добиться результат такого как в стандартных записях - `Home / Taxonomy / Term / Single Post`? Из-за этой проблемы некорректно работают хлебные крошки. Ведь если перейти со страницы с категориями (term) на страницу с одним товаром (single post type), то хлебные крошки укажут мне путь как `home / post type / single post`.

**Обновление**

Вот регистрация CPT и Таксономии к ней, может я что-то упустил?

```
function true_register_post_type_init_products() {
...
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'public'             => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'menu_position'      => 20,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'products/products-categories/%products-categories%' )
    );
    register_post_type('products', $args);
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
function add_new_taxonomies_products() {
    register_taxonomy('products-categories',
        array('products'),
        array(
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'public'            => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'show_tagcloud'     => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => array( 'hierarchical' => true ),
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: При регистрации типа записи используйте параметр `permalink_epmask`, чтобы изменить шаблон ссылки на пост: http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/custom-post-type-permalinks

Answer (score 1):

При регистрации типа поста в параметре `slug` указываете соответствующее правило. Например:

```
$args = array(
    ....
    'rewrite' => array(
        ....
        'slug' => 'products-categories/%products-categories%'
    )
);
register_post_type('your_post_type', $args);
```

Если пост находится в термине (элементе таксономии) electronic, то `%products-categories%` преобразуется в `electronic`, ну и т. п.

Comment: Не преобразует. Сcылка такой и осталась 'products-categories/%products-categories%/product-ex/'